# Is an INSERT trigger recursive, or cause an infinite loop?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have an `INSERT` trigger on table. When a row is inserted in table, the `INSERT` trigger is fired.

The trigger's behaviour is such that it will insert another row into the *same table*.

What would be the result of the `INSERT` statement?

Does this `INSERT` result in an infinite loop, or just the expected 2 inserts?

Comment: why does the insert trigger do an additional insert?

Comment: Does the trigger insert into the same table it is defined on?

Answer (score 8):

This is a setting in SQL- see the [CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) msdn page, specifically the section on Recursive Triggers. The setting you need to look into is RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS, if this is false, a trigger on Table1 will not trigger another insert into Table1. If you do allow recursive triggers, the limit is 32 levels deep.